# i3wm: Cycling throw workspaces

Tags: i3

I’m back using i3 as my main window manager, but I notice something I’ve never done before:

When the leftmost workspace is focused and I try to switch to the previous one (`workspace prev`), i3 jumps to the rightmost, and contrariwise (`workspace next` makes it jump to the leftmost workspace).

I’d like i3 to do nothing when the leftmost workspace is focused and the I try to switch to the previous; and the so the same for the rightmost one switching to the next.

Is there a way to set it?